# Problem with ArrayFlatten to concatenate matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to concatenate 2 matrix :
- the first which is a line of 2 elements
- the second which is a matrix of 2-2 elements

I use the following code :

```
B = ArrayFlatten[{{Simplify[
      Inverse[Subscript[\[Phi], Subscript[q, d]]].Subscript[\[Phi], 
       Subscript[q, i]]]}, {IdentityMatrix[2]}}] // MatrixForm
```

But it doesn't work ie that I didn't manage to obtain the following matrix :

```
B={{1/2 l Sin[\[Gamma][t]], -(1/2) l Cos[\[Gamma][t]]}, {1, 0}, {0, 
   1}} // MatrixForm
```

May you help me to better use the ArrayFlatten function or a another function so as to concatenate 2 matrix.

Thank you

Comment: "But it doesn't work": Actually, your expression *does* work, but perhaps it does not produce what you want. If you don't tell us what you need, we can't help you.

Comment: As a side note, you probably don't want to store the `MatrixForm` of your matrix in `B`, as MatrixForm is intended for formatting only, and no good for further calculations; rewrite your expression as `(B = ...) // MatrixForm`.

Comment: Simplify[Inverse[Subscript[\[Phi], Subscript[q, d]]].Subscript[\[Phi],
   Subscript[q, i]]]={{1/2 l Sin[\[Gamma][t]]}, {-(1/2) l Cos[\[Gamma][t]]}}
in order to help for the troubleshooting and I would like to obtain a matrix with 3 lines of 3 columns :
Line 1 : 1/2 l Sin[\[Gamma][t]], -(1/2) l Cos[\[Gamma][t]]
Line 2: 1, 0
Line 3: 0,1

Comment: Please add any explanation to your original question, not in a comment. Comments break formatting. Please add an example of a matrix that would satisfy your requirements in your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
Join[{{1/2 l Sin[γ[t]], -(1/2) l Cos[γ[t]]}}, IdentityMatrix[2]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Observe the double brackets around the first argument of `Join`

Many more possibilities like `Insert`, `Prepend`

Comment: OK. Great. Does it also possible with ArrayFlatten function ?

Comment: `ArrayFlatten` is not possible here

Comment: Huh? Isn't this the same as `a = {{1/2 l Sin[\[Gamma][t]], -(1/2) l Cos[\[Gamma][t]]}}; b = 
 IdentityMatrix[2]; ArrayFlatten[{{a}, {b}}] // MatrixForm`? @Bendesarts Why do you insist on `ArrayFlatten`?

Comment: It was just because it seems to me that the notations are a bit more simple. Thank you for your help

Comment: Somebody can remind me the rule about the double brackets around the first argument of Join ?

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayFlatten` can be used as follows:

```
a = {{1/2 l Sin[γ[t]], -(1/2) l Cos[γ[t]]}};
b = IdentityMatrix[2];
ArrayFlatten[{{a}, {b}}]
```